# Сохранение данных в форме

Tags: forms, cookie, html, javascript

У меня имеются textarea и input теги, я хочу, чтобы при в вводе, после каждого символа, в поля информация сохранялась в coockie с названием созвучным с name (желательнее) или id, а после нажатия на button, все стиралось (из cookie).
Помогите пожалуйста реализовать это на JavaScript

Comment: Если нельзя в cookie то куда нибудь в другое место, но так, чтобы можно было бы извлечь с помощью PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getCookie(c_name)
 {
 var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
 for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
   {
   x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
   y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
   x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
   if (x==c_name)
     {
     return unescape(y);
     }
   }
 }

 function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
 {
 var exdate=new Date();
 exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
 var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
 document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
 }

 function checkCookie()
 {
 var username=getCookie("username");
 if (username!=null && username!="")
   {
   alert("Welcome again " + username);
   }
 else 
   {
   username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (username!=null && username!="")
     {
     setCookie("username",username,365);
     }
   }
 }

var element = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
element.onkeyup = function(){
var val = element.value;
setCookie("user1",val,17);//Вместо user1 вставьте любой идентификатор, уникальный для данного пользователя и текстового поля. Как вы его добудете - уже не мои проблемы. =) Кука живет в данном случае 17 дней.

}
```

Comment: А можете по подробнее, пожалуйста.
Что делает каждая из функций в этом случае?

Comment: setCookie - записывает в куку данные.
getCookie - достает из куки данные.
checkCookie - один из примеров использования кук.

4 строки внизу - пример использования для вашего случая.